# How to install Win 8.1 to HDD as booting it from SSD?

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, partitioning, ssd

I try to install Win 8.1 to my new computer with both SSD and HDD. I want to boot it from SSD but keep the all related files in HDD. Is it possible to choose such a scheme for the installation ?

If you know Linux, then what I want is pretty similar to create /boot partition at SSD and keep all /root /home partitions at HDD. However, in the installation process of Win 8.1, I cannot see any advance partition tool to define such detail schema.

Comment: I guess you got me wrong. I need a separate boot partition on SSD but keep the data in HDD. It provides that the PC will boot from SSD but keep running on HDD

Comment: no no no. Still wrong. I want all my system files and stuff in HDD but only boot related things in SSD. The only storage I need in SSD is something like 120 MB for the whole Boot files of Win. If you know Ubuntu, it is pretty similar to defining a /boot partition at SSD while keeping all /home /root stuff at HDD.

Comment: I cannot understand why you would like something like this. I don't know about Ubuntu or Linux, I know that all my system files and programs are in C:\ (SSD) and all my Documents, Downloads, etc. is in my HDD. You just go to your User Profile and look into the respective documents, and then change their default *physical* folders. Something in concept similar to symbolic links.

BTW, don't over burden yourself with super duper customizations for SSD life longevity, just enjoy it.

Comment: @Erogol - What you want isn't possible.  What I described earlier is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is just installing Windows on the HDD. After booting into it, create a boot environment on the partition on the SSD.

You do that using [bcdboot.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744347(v=ws.10).aspx), e.g.

```
  bcdboot C:\Windows /s E: /f ALL
```

Then you have to add an entry to the bcd store on the SSD pointing to your harddrive partition (using bcdedit.exe). Also change the boot order in your BIOS to boot from the SSD.

You need to investigate the exact commands a bit more, I just outlined the general procedure here.

The whole thing doesn't really give you much benefits, loading the few boot files will make hardly any difference between a HDD and SSD, having the Windows OS on the SSD gives you the performance boost.

Comment: I doubt it’ll make any measurable difference at all. Unlike `/boot` on Linux, the BCD partition is not where the kernel resides. The only thing “profiting” here is the boot manager (like Grub), which is only a few megs.

Comment: As I see from both comments, keeping boot section in SSD does not work as supposed in Linux. What you guys suggest to boost the startup time using SSD? I don't want to keep all windows in SSD since it means too much write operation that shorten the SSD life.

Comment: Put Windows on the SSD, I'm doing that for years. The lifetime of SSDs is much better nowadays. If you ever used Windows from an SSD you never want to go back to a HDD.

Comment: @Erogol Even with Linux you’d have to put `/` on the SSD to actually profit. I recommend putting everything on your SSD, especially swap. Because that’s what profits the most.